# Silverlight C# - How to copy line of text that is clicked in textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a textbox that I break up into an array based on "\r"

I'd like to have the line of text that is clicked on put into a string.

For instance, if I click on the 2nd line below in my textbox, I'd like "2nd line" to be entered into the string

> 1st line
>   2nd line
>   last line

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Why aren't you splitting on `"\r\n"`, the Windows new line character?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer as I ended up grabbing the string out of a datagrid I was populating with data out of the textbox referenced in this post.

Link to that solution is: [Silverlight C# - How to get value of row/cell clicked on in DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700092/silverlight-c-how-to-get-value-of-row-cell-clicked-on-in-datagrid)

Comment: -1: totally different that what you were asking for in this question.  This answer isn't relevant to your question at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is close, but I recommend selecting text between TextBox.SelectionStart and TextBox.SelectionEnd instead of what you are trying to do.

*WPF, but it might be the same*

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TextBox
  MouseDoubleClick="textBox1_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int characterIndex = this.textBox1.SelectionStart;
  string characterIndexSubstring = this.textBox1.Text.Substring(0, characterIndex);
  int lineNumber = characterIndexSubstring.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
  string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  string clickedOnValue = lines[lineNumber];
  MessageBox.Show(clickedOnValue);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's mostly there, but it always returns row[0] because there's no code in it to actually collect which row was actually clicked on, therefore it defaults to 0.