# Silverlight C# - How to get value of row/cell clicked on in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

I've got a DataGrid that I'm populating with data, and I'd like to copy the value of the cell clicked on into a string. Better yet, **I'd like to copy the value out of a specific cell in the row, so if there's a way to load the entire row into an array that'd be better**.

For instance I'd have a few rows like this:

```
Included | Keyword     | Occurrences | Density
------------------------------------------------
   Yes   | KW1         |     3       |   1.02%
   Yes   | Keyword2    |     1       |   0.25%
   Yes   | KW1         |     3       |   1.021%
```

If I were to click anywhere on row 2 I'd like to be able to load the row into an array so that it I'd be able to call gridrow[1] in order to consistently get the value "Keyword2".

**Also**:

In the older Silverlights, to open up a new webpage I'd use HtmlPage.Navigate, but that doesn't appear to work in Silverlight 4. (Yes, I've loaded System.Windows.Browser; )

Thanks in advance!

-Sootah

Comment: Also, I have a function that returns the entire list, but as I have no real experience with the list<> datatype, I've no idea how to use it.

Perhaps it's possible to get the index of the row clicked on, and then somehow access keywordlist.keyword[#] or something?

Comment: Am I right, that you just need the selected row. If this changes you want the new selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DataGrid.SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)  to get the data bound to the selected row.

Comment: Well that was easy enough! Your solution was by FAR the simplest I've seen. Since I only wanted to grab the content out of a certain column, I ended up using the following code:

if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 1)
                mystring = ((TextBlock)dataGrid.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(dataGrid.SelectedItem)).Text;